# How do I validate a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

Have a text input box.
Would like the user to enter a string in the exact format:

```
2010/08/26 17:04:51.24
```

(with any numbers of course)

How can I do this efficiently?

Not looking for the answer, just a point in the right direction.

Thank You.

(html, JavaScript and jQuery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info) would be the most obvious solution. That being said, you probably don't want to go through the trouble of implementing a regular expression for matching dates and times when you can instead use an already existing solution.

[DateJs](http://www.datejs.com/) is a really great JavaScript date parser that handles converting user-entered dates and times into meaningful values. DateJs can intelligently parse natural language expressions like "tomorrow" or "+5 days" and also standard date and time representations like "10/24/2008 11:31:04 AM".

Comment: DateJs looks good but I put my string in and it didn't know what to do! I think regular expressions are the way to go.

Comment: I think it's the ".24" at the end that it doesn't know how to handle. Is that significant?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd want a regular expression to do this. I don't know of any other way to validate format other than that. I'm sure there are some libraries/plugins, but they probably just use a regular expression inside of them.

Edit: Nathan Taylor is right, DateJS is pretty great.